# Cancel button navigation in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, navigation

I have a cancel button on a page.
But this page can be opened from different places. I mean the parent page can vary.

Now, by clicking on the cancel button I need to go back to the exact page where I came from - like `history.back()`.

How can we implement it in JSF?

Can someone please guide me?

And that `history.back()` directly is not working.

```
<h:commandButton type="button" id="cancel" image="#{sessionScope.sessionObject.graphicImageFolderName}cancel_btn.gif" accesskey="#{bundle.oscer_command_cancel_accesskey}" value="Cancel" action="#{templatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean.goBack}" />
```

In case of `history.back()` I am making the same button as..

```
<h:commandButton type="button" id="cancel" image="#{sessionScope.sessionObject.graphicImageFolderName}cancel_btn.gif" accesskey="#{bundle.oscer_command_cancel_accesskey}" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript: history.back();"/>
```

Is there anything wrong in both of the cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<h:commandLink onclick="history.go(-1); return false;">
```

Or

```
<h:commandButton onclick="history.back(); return false;">
```

work for you?

Comment: Thanks Daniel,

I did **<h:commandButton onclik="history.back(); return false"** and that works for me.

Thanks alot. You are great.

Comment: @Daniel there is a problem with this approach. Suppose on page A you click submit then page B gets opened now if you click cancel on page B page A will come. Now here is the twist, if you try cancel on page A, it will open page B.

Comment: @AjaySharma , I guess there are other solutions beside mine

Answer (score 1):

Get the default navigation handler via [Application.getNavigationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getNavigationHandler%28%29). Wrap it in a [reflection proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and set the proxy as new default navigation handler via [Application.setNavigationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/application/Application.html#setNavigationHandler%28javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler%29). In the proxy's invocation handler, you can track all navigation events with their outcomes, and build your own history from  this. Then use this history to handle the "cancel" button's navigation, by going back in your history.

Comment: Thanks Sylar,
Your answer is very generalized. Not tried yet. But will surely try it. Thank you very much. You are great.